# How to prevent emacs annoying habit of adding the current word to any command buffer?

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

Whenever I c-x c-f, emacs adds the current word at the cursor point to the c-x c-f.

I believe this is probably due to ido.

**How can I turn this off?**

Comment: Need more information.  It is definitely something in your .emacs, but a simple `(require 'ido)` isn't enough to cause the behavior you're seeing...  What does `C-h k C-x C-f` tell you is bound to that key binding?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I use eschulte's emacs-starter-kit and that it isn't just c-x c-f that does this, ido just adds the current word at pointer to its autocompletion for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an ido option that's usually not activated by default. It can be turned off with this line:

```
(setq ido-use-filename-at-point nil)
```